# Why is My Regex Code not working on DART?

Tags: regex, dart

I fetched data from a web sites body.Then I write a regular expression and applied on DART but it didnt work.What is the Problem?

Here is the Regex code:

```
</td><td align="left">(.*?)</td><td class="dataGridActive
```

Here is my part of the content:

```
</tr><tr onmouseover="mover(this);" onmouseout="mout(this);" style="background-color:White;">
            <td align="left">233</td><td align="left">ÖMER EFE CIKIT</td><td class="dataGridActive" align="center">
```

And the dart code:

```
void CheckRE(String text) {
    final RegExp pattern = RegExp(
      r'</td><td align="left">(.*?)</td><td class="dataGridActive"',
      multiLine: true,
      caseSensitive: true,
    ); // 800 is the size of each chun
    pattern
        .allMatches(text)
        .forEach((RegExpMatch match) => print(match.group(1)));
  }
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @julemand101    'ÖMER EFE CIKIT'

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is the following.

I have changed your output so it prints the content of capture group 1 instead of capture group 0. Capture group 0 contains the whole string which matches while 1 and up contains the content of each defined capture group in your regular expression.

```
const input = '''
</tr><tr onmouseover="mover(this);" onmouseout="mout(this);" style="background-color:White;">
            <td align="left">233</td><td align="left">ÖMER EFE CIKIT</td><td class="dataGridActive" align="center">
''';

void main() => checkRE(input); // ÖMER EFE CIKIT

void checkRE(String text) {
  final RegExp pattern = RegExp(
    r'</td><td align="left">(.*?)</td><td class="dataGridActive"',
    multiLine: true,
    caseSensitive: true,
  ); // 800 is the size of each chun
  pattern.allMatches(text).forEach((RegExpMatch match) => print(match[1]));
}
```

Also changed `(.*)` to `(.*?)` based on advice from @MikeM.

Comment: I have updated the problem parts. But still same. Doesn't return anything

Comment: @Cellesss Could you make a self-contained program, like I have done, which reproduces your issue? If I copy your code and input, it works fine for me when running in DartVM.

Comment: I have added as an another Comment.